# Prometheus REST API inconsistent results

Tags: prometheus

I use the following URL to get the process cpu usage from prometheus. But when I click several times on this url it shows me different data. Please advise.

*https://prometheusXYZ/api/v1/query_range?query=process_cpu_usage%7Bnamespace%3D%22ABC%22%2Ccontainer%3D%22DEF%22%7D&start=1687851040.0969799&end=1687851940.096981&step=4*

For example, once first 3 points are *[1687851040.097,"0.01"],[1687851044.097,"0.01"],[1687851048.097,"0.01"]*, and other time: *[1687851040.097,"0.007650273224043716"],[1687851044.097,"0.007650273224043716"],[1687851048.097,"0.007650273224043716"]*